# webpack doesn't bundle node modules

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-externals

I want to require a module from node_modules and I want to bundle it (for test purposes), but Webpack behaves as if it is added to externals.

```
// no externals or any plugin used
let config = {
    mode: 'none',
    target: 'node',
    entry: {
      output: `/example.js`,
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js'],
    },
    output: {
      path: './dist',
    },
  };
```

```
// exampl.js
require('path')
```

```
// dist/output.js
require('path');
```

**Expected behavior**

the node module `path` to be bundled

**actual behavior**

Webpack keep `require('path');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. When you set `target: 'node'` in webpack config, webpack will not bundle the built-ins module of Node.js. `path` is a built-in module of Node.js, it doesn't come from the `node_modules` directory.

> using `node` webpack will compile for usage in a Node.js-like environment (uses Node.js require to load chunks and not touch any built in modules like `fs` or `path`).

See [targets](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/#usage)